# how to create an id number that look like this: 00001...00002....?

Tags: c, for-loop

I need to create several id's for several structs.
Now I want that each id will start from 00001 to 99999

for example:

- the id of the first struct is 00001
- the id of the second struct is 00002
- ...and so on...

Now I need to `scanf` it, and then `printf` it so the id that shown in the black window will look like this: `The id of the first struct is: 00001`

How do I do this?

Do I need to use regular `int` or `double`?

And how do i use a loop `for (i=0 ; i<99999 ;i++)`
while i is the last digits?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It can't be an `int` or `double` because they don't have leading zeroes The *representation* of an int could have leading zeroes, but that's something slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a numerical variable, there is no concept of "leading zeroes". So if you want to use "0001" in your code, you will have to convert it into a string, adding leading 0's as required.

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: i did it like this                                                f1.Id=00001;

 printf("\nThis is the ID for the new field: ");
 for (i=1 ; i<5 ; i++)
  printf("0");
 printf("%d\n",f1.Id);   but i feels wrong                                                  s

Answer (score 1):

You can store the id as a normal `int`.

When you need to print it, simply use an appropriate [format string](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/printf.html) for `printf`, like so:

```
printf("id = %05d\n", i);
```

A working example is available [here](http://ideone.com/7zT5z).

In the format string, the `%05d` means:

- `%` means it's a formatting parameter
- `0` means that you want the number zero padded
- `5` means that you want it 5 digits wide
- `d` means that it's an integer you want to print

Answer (score 0):

There are formatting options which can be given to the printf formatting string :

```
 printf("The id of the first struct is: %05d",id);
```

[here is a nice overview](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html) of the formatting options